# How to align images vertically centered by using subfloat?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, subfloats

I am using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[t]%
        \centering
        \subfloat[Image 1\label{fig:img1}]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{img1.png} }}%
        \subfloat[Image 2\label{fig:img2}]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{img2.png} }}%
        \caption{Two images}%
        \label{fig:imgs}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However img1 and img2 have different heights but same width. How do I display them at vertically alligned position? Basically the center of both the images should be at the same horizontal line.

Comment: And where should be images caption? It would be helpful, if you will extend your code snippet to complete small document. Welcome to Tex.SE! i

Comment: Captions should be aligned together, only the images should be centered

Comment: Please always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of only a code snippet. Currently we, e.g., can only speculate which package you are using to have `\subfloat`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

One of among possible solutions for above figure is enclose smaller image in `tikz` node with minimum height equal to height of taller image. This means, that you need first to measure its height and than accordingly set TikZ node size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\imageheight% for determining height of taller image

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]%
% measurement of height of the taller image
\settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img1.png}}
    \centering
% since I haven't your image,
% I simulate their different heights with prescribed "height"
\subfloat[Image 1\label{fig:img1}]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img1.png}}%
\hfil
\subfloat[Image 2\label{fig:img2}]{\tikz\node[minimum height=\imageheight]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img2.png}}; }%
    \caption{Two images}%
\label{fig:imgs}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what does `ht` in `\begin{figure}[ht]` do?

Comment: `ht` are options for figure placement: here (where is inserted in text), if there is enough space, otherwise on the top of the next page. Tank you for completing of your code snippet. Now I complete my answer and also add some more explanation, See, if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `minipage` grid:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b} \\
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      \subcaption{Image 1}\label{fig:img1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      \subcaption{Image 2\label{fig:img2}}%
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Two images}%
    \label{fig:imgs}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]